# Scaling image in ImageView to full size

Tags: java, android, image, imageview

I have an ImageView and an extern image which gets load into the ImageView on start. The problem is: the image doesn't have the height of the device. The width is correctly full size. How can I achieve the image to be as high as the deviceheight so that it is fullscreen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**If you don't care about aspect ratio** , use

```
android:adjustViewBounds="false" 
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

Or if programatically...

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.fullImage);
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Display mDisplay= activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int width= mDisplay.getWidth();
int Height= mDisplay.getHeight();
```

You can get the device height and set the imageview's height programmatically.

```
imageView.getLayoutParams().height = Height;
```

Answer (score 0):

First set width and height of your imageview to match_parent

There are few [scale type](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html) provided by imageview widget in android :

out of which,  I use centerCrop very often because it maintains the aspect ratio but you can find what suits you better.

```
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

also don't forget to write this line in  your xml :

```
android:adjustViewBounds="false"
```